# Android Button with Custom View. ImageView + Text to Right

Tags: android

I need to replace simple Icon buttons or ImageView's with CustomView.  So the button looks like:

```
: ImageView   "Request Tweets"  :
```

This is just a relative layout of course or even a LinearLayout, but my question is how to implement it as a button? I looked at ImageButton but I am not trying to set a background image as much as I am trying to have both image and text act as a Button.

Comment: you can simply use text view with drawable left..it will work for you

Comment: Oh yes! That's right. Do you happen to know how to set the margin between the drawable left and the text?

Comment: Thai check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:drawablePadding="10dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@drawable/preview_dailog_bg"
        android:text="swipe_element"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for the custom view handling "on click" event, you can simply implement the onClickListener as it is available for View. You can take a look to this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)